# how to get AUROC at 5% false positive

Tags: classification, roc, auc, metric

How can I get AUROC at 5% false positives. I am not quite sure how to do that, is it possible to get it from full area under the curve or it has to be calculated from validation set?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

A ROC curve displays the trade-off between true and false positive rates (or sensitivity/specificity) by varying the decision threshold over all possible thresholds. Therefore the curve integrates over all possible false positive rates between 0% and 100%. You cannot have a curve for a single false positive rate, only a single point at best.

I suggest to read [Understanding ROC curve and the answers to the question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105501/understanding-roc-curve) and [An introduction to ROC analysis by Fawcett](http://people.inf.elte.hu/kiss/13dwhdm/roc.pdf).